# Cannot figure out what is wrong with this Update Query code for MS Access

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

Imported a table (I DEV) from MS Excel, trying to update an MS Access table (PLA HIST). The tables have identical ID columns. I keep getting error messages from Access when I try to run it.

```
UPDATE PLA HIST
INNER JOIN I DEV 
ON I DEV.ID = PLA HIS.ID
SET PLA HIS.[num] = I DEV.[number];
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky but good coding practice is to never use spaces in table or field names, and never use ["reserved words"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe).  I see people use words like Date, Year, Note, Group, etc... as field names a lot, and this **always** causes problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put square brackets around all identifiers that contain spaces.

```
UPDATE [PLA HIST]
INNER JOIN [I DEV]
ON [I DEV].ID = [PLA HIS].ID
SET [PLA HIS].[num] = [I DEV].[number];
```